# SQL Reporting Services - how to display left joined data on two axis

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, charts, sql-server-2008-r2

Sorry people, this is not an easy one to describe but I have a dataset in Reporting services to display a chart.  The dataset is a result of a LEFT JOIN to combine database data file sizes and the disk size of the relevant Disk.  The chart I am trying to design would have a stacked bar chart with each bar being the stacked data file sizes on a date timeline X axis.  I can create such a chart, no problem but... If I add in the disk size, because it's a repeated value per database, it appears twice, which is not what I want.

A simplified version of the dataset result set would look like..

```
DateTime     DBName DBDataFileSize Drive DriveSize
2018-08-10   DB1    100            D     300
2018-08-10   DB2    150            D     300
2018-08-11   DB1    100            D     500
2018-08-11   DB2    160            D     500
2018-08-12   DB1    100            D     500
2018-08-12   DB2    170            D     500
2018-08-13   DB1    110            D     1000
2018-08-13   DB2    180            D     1000
```

So, in this example, there would be 4 stacked bars showoing DB1 and DB2 using DBDataFileSize.   All fine so far but I can't find out how to add the DriveSize as a Secondary Y axis and only show that value once per common X value axis?  I would like to show the DriveSize values as a Line above the stacked bars.

By the way, I have a fairly old version of SQL Server and Reporting Services in this case.  2008 R2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to pivot your data so that it has separate columns for each KPI, instead of a different row. All I can really offer without sample data. *On a different note, 2008 is almost completely out of support, so you really should be looking at upgrading that sooner rather than later; especially if you want to remain GDPR compliant.*

Comment: Yes, I was coming around to the Pivot conclusion as well.  Thanks for confirming.